# Prove that $\tau=\{\eta(A):A\in {P}(A)\}$ is a topology on $X$ and $\eta(A)=\operatorname{Int}(A)$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\eta:{P}(A)\to{P}(A)$ a map such that

- a) $\eta(X)=X$
- b) $\eta(A)\subset A$
- c) $\eta\circ\eta(A)$=$\eta(A)$
- d) $\eta(A\cap B)=\eta(A)\cap \eta(B)$

Prove that $\tau=\{\eta(A):A\in {P}(A)\}$ is a topology on $X$ and $\eta(A)=\operatorname{Int}(A)$.

**Proof:** For $\tau=\{\eta(A):A\in {P}(A)\}$ is a topology on $X$.

- $\emptyset\in\tau$ since $\emptyset\in {P}(A)$ and also by a) $X\in\tau$.

My question is how to prove the intersection and union is in $\tau$? Is my $\emptyset$ and $X$ correct? Also, help me to prove $\eta(A)=\operatorname{Int}(A)$.

Thank you so much.

Comment: (b) makes (c) and (d) redundant.

Comment: In case $\eta$ is such a function, then $\tau = \{\eta(X) \ | \ X \in \mathcal{P}(A)\} = \mathcal{P}(A)$ which is trivially a topology on $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Yes, you're right. It is $\eta(A)\subseteq A$. Sorry for that. Can you show me the detailed proof? Is my $\emptyset$ and $X$ argument correct>

Comment: $\emptyset\in\tau$ because (b) implies $\emptyset = \eta(\emptyset)$.

Answer (score 2):

If (b) is actually $\eta(A)\subset A$, the axioms are the duals of [Kuratowski closure axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms). See the section [Induction of Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms#Induction_of_Topology).

EDIT:
The space is open because (a). The empty set is open because (b). Finite intersection of open sets is open because of (d). And arbitrary union of open sets is open because if $A_i = \eta(A_i)$ for all $i\in I$:
$$\eta\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$$
and... can you continue?

Comment: I read link in Kuratowski closure axioms. It is about closure. Is it the same with $\eta$?

Comment: @Bayoy, isn't the same, is the *dual*. $A\mapsto X\setminus\eta(A)$ is a closure operator.

Comment: Oh no! I am new in topology and my instructor assign me this without discussing the topic.. Can you help me the proof specially $\eta(A)=Int(A)$. Thank you

Comment: @Bayoy, $\eta = \operatorname{Int}$ is consequence of (c).

Comment: @Bayoy, correction: $A\mapsto X\setminus\eta(X\setminus A)$ is a closure operator.

Comment: Ok.I will continue this. At least I have an idea now. Thank you so much.